# Python 2.7.4 Installation Location

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just installed the new version of Python (2.7.4) for Mac.  The binaries from the website installed it at

```
> which python

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

My `/usr/bin/python` was still 2.7.2 though.

I did `cp /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /usr/bin` so that I can type `#!/usr/bin/python` to use 2.7.4 and also so IPython would use 2.7.4

My question is:

Did I create any caveats by doing this or should I be safe?

Comment: What Python distribution (Homebrew, OS X, ?) did you have installed before?

Comment: Homebrew.  `brew install python --framework` tries to get 2.7.3 though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing software an OS installs it self and probably regularly updates could lead to caveats. That's why there are *Package Managers* like [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/). They try to do this in a controlled manner and separate their software packages from the packages of the OS.

Each with their on philosophy: MacPorts tries to separate it a little more from the OS than Homebrew does, the latter shares more OS libaries.

A Package Manager could make it also easy to switch between different versions. With MacPorts you do:

```
$ port select --list python
vailable versions for python:
    none
    python25-apple
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
    python27-apple
```

To change back to the OS version:

```
$ sudo port select python27-apple
```

MacPort does this by changing symbolic links. MacPorts puts it's packages in a separate tree (`/opt/local`). For this you need to have your *PATH* changed: `/opt/local/bin` and `/opt/local/sbin` need to be in there before `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` (see [MacPorts installation)

```
$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  24 Dec  5  2011 /opt/local/bin/python -> /opt/local/bin/python2.7
```